# Java: Encryption of email

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, encryption

I am currently encrypting emails, so this line of regular expression is how I encrypt it

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Email: "+"([\\w\\-]([\\-\\.\\w])+[\\w\\-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");
```

However, as I am inserting the encryption email into MYSQL, sometimes the there'll be single quotation appearing that'll disrupt it. So I put,

```
.replace("'", "''")
```

to replace the single quotation to 2 single to escape it. However I have gotten another error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''6d
õYHdoÓÍÄ«Önçä''''¤?\')' at line 1
```

which I assume it is due to the two quotation. Is there another way to edit the regular expression so that it'll be easier to insert into MYSQl?

Comment: What does a regex pattern have to do with encryption? And randomly adding `'` will certainly not prevent sql errors or event sql injection. Why are you even encrypting it?

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to encrypt emails, but anyway regex is used for validating if an input string belongs to a defined set([see formal languages and automata theory](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEto6vp-PWAhUICcAKHWo0A3EQFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAutomata_theory&usg=AOvVaw3HxxEVyPgDAyp3YUSs7JCh)).

If you still want to encrypt, please never implement encryption yourself, use an opensource library like [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).